# Using jq to remove items from an array based on values elsewhere in the input

Tags: json, jq, remove-if

I'm new to `jq` and trying to wrap my head around doing a few things that I thought were going to be straightforward. Any ideas on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated.

Given this input:

```
{
    "source": {
        "items": [
            { "id": "aaa", "name": "this" },
            { "id": "bbb", "name": "that" },
            { "id": "ccc", "name": "the other" }
        ]
    },
    "update": {
        "toRemove": [
            "aaa",
            "ccc"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want this result:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "id": "bbb", "name": "that" }
    ]
}
```

This filter does the job but the variables lead me to believe there is a cleaner way.

```
. as $root | .source + { items: [.source.items[] | select(.id as $id | $root.update.toRemove | contains([$id]) | not)]}
```

Playground link if interested: https://jqplay.org/s/GpVJfbTO-Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a concise and efficient solution:

```
.update.toRemove as $rm
| .source
| .items |= map( select(.id | IN($rm[]) | not))
```

Answer (score 1):

A little shorter version using `inside` instead of `contains`:

```
.update.toRemove as $temp |
 {items: [.source.items[] | select([.id] | inside($temp) | not)]}
```